# SpriteKit: What's the Polyphony of .playSoundFileNamed?

Tags: audio, sprite-kit, skaction

My gut feeling is that this is able to do about 16 or 24 concurrent sounds before it resists playing any new sounds.

But that's just a wild guess. Is there any documentation or other information on the polyphony of this function?